# Rails 3.1 Stylesheets giving trouble, get Routing Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I just created a new app, saw the GemFile and learned now I am using Rails 3.1 which isn't a problem. However, I also learned that now you have to place the Stylesheets, images and other folders in the app/asset folder. I did that, I placed custom.css file in asset folder such that the url would be /asset/stylesheets/custom.css even though I see the file in the asset folder, my stylesheet is not being loaded in the document I get an error

Routing Error
no route matches [get] "assets/stylesheets/custom.css"

How do I fix that?

Some info that might help..
I am using the embedded ruby stylesheet tag 
The code for the stylsheet (header, etc) is placed in the application.html.erb file in the views/layouts folder in an effort to minimize code when I create a new page/controller..

Help much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In application.rb I didn't use

```
require "rails/all"
```

as I don't use ActiveRecord.

I had to add

```
require 'sprockets/railtie'
```

to make asset generation work.

Answer (score 1):

By default custom.css will be merged into application.css, which would have url like this:

```
/assets/application-md5string.css
```

So you could just use this to use it in your layout:

```
= stylesheet_link_tag "application"
```

Comment: EDIT: Application part works, I put the css code from custom in application and deleted the custom.css file which seems to make that stylesheet work..

However, I still cannot load the blueprint.css file... 

Also, to get application to work, I had to downgrade sprockates.